# Not able to get proper URL for streaming video in android

Tags: android, media-player

I am developing an app in android which will stream video from url....but m not able to get proper url ....my app only says video can't be played....will u plzz suggest some good url path for streaming videos?? My code in android if there's any fault in it.......and onPrepared method never called

```
//path="http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8";
        path="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOV49oGr2pc";

        mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }

private void startVideoPlayback(){
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: you are using you tube video then need to parse by youtube then it will be play

Comment: use this url to play the video http://dl.dropbox.com/u/145894/t/rabbits.3gp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to change the way you set up your MediaPlayer. I just plugged the url of your sample video into the apidemos example and it worked just fine.

See: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

also if you just need video links then here they are...

http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/mp4/cavity_flow_movie.mp4

http://mconnect123456.s3.amazonaws.com/9859gizmo.mp4

Hope that helps.